# Using Power Query with Excel, how do I replace a record filled will null values with a single null value?

Tags: excel, type-conversion, powerquery, record, data-conversion

### Problem Summary

I have a column in my Power Query table which contains a custom linked data type. Creating a custom linked data type filled with all null values is not desired. Instead, if all the values contained in the custom data type is null, I would like the value in the column to be null.

### Background

I have a table which holds API response JSON text. This JSON text contains a list of search results (also in JSON), representing movies which match search criteria delivered in the request. There can be any number of search results, including zero. Using Power Query M, I parse these JSON texts with the built-in parser, which generates a `list` containing one `record` per search result. I then extract the first `record` in the `list`, expand that `record` into new columns, and combine those new columns into a custom data type.

### Example

Here is an example query simulating only the problem area of my query. This example is fully contained and can be used to reproduce my issue exactly.

```
let
    // These two variables holds the API response JSON text obtained from calls to Web.Contents().
    // I've eliminated the actual calls in this example because that part of my query works fine.
    Search_Fast_and_Furious_Response =
        "{ ""total-results"":""2"", ""results"":[
            { ""title"":""Fast & Furious"", ""year"":""2009"" },
            { ""title"":""The Fast and the Furious"", ""year"":""2001"" } ] }",
    Search_mmmmm_Response =
        "{ ""total-results"":""0"", ""results"":[] }",
    
    // Create the table to hold the response text.
    Source = Table.FromRecords( { [#"API Response"=Search_Fast_and_Furious_Response],
        [#"API Response"=Search_mmmmm_Response] }),
    
    // Parse the JSON and put the output (a record) in a new column.
    #"Insert Parsed JSON" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "JSON", each Json.Document([API Response])),

    // Expand the record in the parsed JSON column. Each field in the record becomes a new column.
    #"Expand JSON" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Insert Parsed JSON", "JSON",
        {"total-results", "results"}, {"Result Count", "Results List"}),

    // Add a new column to hold the first search result in the responses results list.
    // This is also a record, like the parsed JSON two steps ago.
    #"Add Result #1 Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expand JSON", "Result #1", each
        try         _[Results List]{0}
        otherwise   null),                  // In case the list is empty

    // Expand the record in the Result #1 column.
    #"Expand Result #1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Add Result #1 Column", "Result #1",
        {"title", "year"}, {"Title", "Year"}),

    // Combine the newly expanded columns into a single column.
    // Make the Display Name be the value in the Title field/column,
    // and make the Type Name be "Excel.DataType."
    // This is what creates the custom linked data type.
    #"Combine Result #1" = Table.CombineColumnsToRecord(#"Expand Result #1", "Result #1",
        {"Title", "Year"}, [ DisplayNameColumn = "Title", TypeName="Excel.DataType" ])
in
    #"Combine Result #1"
```

The list in the very last line before the `in` statement, *i.e.* the fourth parameter to the `Table.CombineColumnsToRecord` function, allows the record to be used as a custom data type used with Excel's new linked data feature. I'm not certain, but I believe Power Query/Excel stores them as `record`s with additional metadata, such as `DisplayNameColumn` and `TypeName` (the latter of which I'm sure is the most important part).

### Problem and Goal

Here is the resulting table created by the example query. The bottom-right cell is selected. Its contents are shown at the bottom of the image. The cell itself contains a value, specifically a record with all values set to null. Because the Title field is null, the record's display text is "null."

[image: Problem]

This next picture shows my desired output. Notice again the bottom-right cell. This time, the cell is empty. It no longer contains a record with all values being null; now it contains nothing, so the display shown in this view is *null*, italicized so as to indicate a null value as opposed to the word "null." (Note: I've been unable to change the "null" cell in the first image to a literal null value, so to demonstrate, I simply added a new column of null values.)

[image: Goal]

Unfortunately, because of my `otherwise` clause after the `try`, the column "Result #1" may be null if the API returned zero search results. If this value is null in any row, then all of the new columns created by `#"Expand Result #1"` will contain null in that row, also. Finally, when all the null values are combined in the last step, I'm left with a `record` with all null values. Instead, what I hope to achieve is to have a single null value (of type `null`) in that cell.

### Efforts So Far

I have tried the `Table.ReplaceValues` function, passing null as the new value and many different values as the old value (the one to be replaced), such as a new record with all null values. All those attempts have either been syntactically incorrect or resulted in expected and unwanted behavior. I have also tried using the "Replace Values" option in the Power Query GUI, but the same result occurs. In case `ReplaceValues` didn't like nulls, I've also tried using a different value in the `otherwise` clause, such as "N/A" of type text, then doing a `ReplaceValues` on that different value. This yielded the same result.

### Conclusion

Is there any way I can replace a record—which is filled with null values and is stored in a column containing records—with a singular null value? The linked data type feature is a high priority in this situation, so I would prefer a solution that retains that feature (though of course all solutions are welcome).

Comment: A representative data sample (posted as **text**) and example of intended results would be useful to be able to assist you.  Might be helpful to read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  The **edit your question** to provide more useful information.

Comment: Thank you, @RonRosenfeld! I appreciate the assistance. After reading those pages, I believe I have already provided a mostly complete "reprex," though I will flesh it out a little more and "start from scratch" with my example. I will also include a representative data sample.

Comment: To check if the value in `Result#1` is `*null*`, you can check the value of the `Title` column. eg:  `if Record.Field([#"Result #1"],"Title")=null then null else [#"Result #1"]`  But this does not preserve the data type. How important is that? Can you live without it; or set up your data type afterwards?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks again! I'm going to answer my own question fully in the next day or so (on vacation at the moment), but your suggestion is pretty much what I did: I set up my data type later. I knew I could check the value of Title being null, but it hadn't occurred to me until two days ago that I could simple _wait_ to create the data type until _after_ I've dealt with the nulls. I separate the null rows from the non-nulls into a separate table, perform the data type creation on the non-nulls, then put the two tables together again at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I have "solved" my problem. While not technically a solution to the question I posted, I've achieved the desired result using a workaround.

Instead of dealing with the object full of null fields, I ensure that object is not converted to the custom object to begin with. I achieve this by moving all records with a null value after extracting the first List item in the Results List column; this is done before I expand that extracted item. After putting the nulls in a new table (which I call the Null Table), I delete those nulls from the first table (which I call the Non-Null Table). I perform the regular operations on the Non-Null Table to create the custom linked data type for only those rows that were not null. Afterward, I merge the two tables together again.

The full code containing the solution with my representative example is below, with new steps "highlighted" with non-indented comments.

```
let
    // These two variables holds the API response JSON text obtained from calls to Web.Contents().
    // I've eliminated the actual calls in this example because that part of my query works fine.
    Search_Fast_and_Furious_Response =
        "{ ""total-results"":""2"", ""results"":[
            { ""title"":""Fast & Furious"", ""year"":""2009"" },
            { ""title"":""The Fast and the Furious"", ""year"":""2001"" } ] }",
    Search_mmmmm_Response =
        "{ ""total-results"":""0"", ""results"":[] }",
    
    // Create the table to hold the response text.
    Source = Table.FromRecords( { [#"API Response"=Search_Fast_and_Furious_Response],
        [#"API Response"=Search_mmmmm_Response] }),
    
    // Parse the JSON and put the output (a record) in a new column.
    #"Insert Parsed JSON" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "JSON", each Json.Document([API Response])),

    // Expand the record in the parsed JSON column. Each field in the record becomes a new column.
    #"Expand JSON" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Insert Parsed JSON", "JSON",
        {"total-results", "results"}, {"Result Count", "Results List"}),

    // Add a new column to hold the first search result in the responses results list.
    // This is also a record, like the parsed JSON two steps ago.
    #"Add Result #1 Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expand JSON", "Result #1", each
        try         _[Results List]{0}
        otherwise   null),                  // In case the list is empty

// New step
    // Filter down to only rows with null in the new column. Save this new table for later.
    #"Filter In Null" = Table.SelectRows(#"Add Result #1 Column", each _[#"Result #1"] = null),

// New step
    // Filter down to only rows with NOT null in the new column.
    #"Filter Out Null" = Table.SelectRows(#"Add Result #1 Column", each _[#"Result #1"] <> null),

    // Expand the record in the Result #1 column.
    #"Expand Result #1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Filter Out Null", "Result #1",
        {"title", "year"}, {"Title", "Year"}),

    // Combine the newly expanded columns into a single column.
    // Make the Display Name be the value in the Title field/column,
    // and make the Type Name be "Excel.DataType."
    // This is what creates the custom linked data type.
    #"Combine Result #1" = Table.CombineColumnsToRecord(#"Expand Result #1", "Result #1",
        {"Title", "Year"}, [ DisplayNameColumn = "Title", TypeName="Excel.DataType" ]),

// New step
    // Convert the Null Table into a list of records.
    #"Convert Table" = Table.ToRecords(#"Filter In Null"),

// New step
    // Append the Null Table from earlier to the main table.
    #"Combine Tables" = Table.InsertRows(#"Combine Result #1", Table.RowCount(#"Combine Result #1"),
        #"Convert Table")
in
    #"Combine Tables"
```